# Phantomjs and async scraping

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping, phantomjs, async.js

This is basic phantom code with async I'm using. I removed all extra code from inside (filters) to look cleaner. So, idea is to find all links on starting page and push them to queue. I also pushed them to array called allurls. Then inside queue all links from starting page are scraped to find links inside them. Links that are found are also pushed to array allurls. But, problem is that I don't want only those links, I want to scrap all pages for all links until all of them are found, but I want to do it with async. But, because there can be huge amount of links, I would like to limit that queue scraps 10 pages and when it is finished to go to the next 10 pages. I was trying to increase concurrency and push all links from allurls to queue, but unsuccessfully. What is the proper way to do this?

```
var async = require('async');
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    page.open(task.url, function(status) { 
        if(status !== 'success') 
        {

        } 
        else    
        {
            // Evaluate and find links
            var xlinks = page.evaluate(function() {
                var TotalLinks = [];
                var xmatches = document.querySelectorAll('a'); 
                    for(var i = 0; i < xmatches.length; i++) {
                            TotalLinks.push(xmatches[i].href);  
                       }
                        return TotalLinks;
            });
            xlinks.forEach(function(xlink) {
                allurls.push({urls: xlink});
            });
        }           
        callback();
    });
}, 1);


q.drain = function() {
    phantom.exit();  // Exiting
}

"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system');
var startUrl = system.args[1];  
var allurls = [];

//Opening Starting Url
page.open(startUrl, function(status) {
    if(status !== 'success') 
    { 
    } 
    else 
    {   
        // Find links on starting url
        var zlinks = page.evaluate(function() {
                var StartTotalLinks = [];  
                var zmatches = document.querySelectorAll('a');  
                    for(var i = 0; i < zmatches.length; i++) {
                        StartTotalLinks.push(zmatches[i].href); 
                    }
                    return StartTotalLinks; 
        }); 
        zlinks.forEach(function(zlink) {
            q.push({url: zlink});
            allurls.push({urls: zlink});
        });
    }   
});
```